# How to check if a string is a valid DATE, TIME or DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, validation, datetime

When I try to put a value into a DATE field which is invalid, MySQL seems to use 0000-00-00 instead. Is there a way I can do this "check" without updating a DATE field? And to do it from for example PHP?

Like, is there a way I can query the MySQL server and ask "Hey, is this DATE, TIME or DATETIME valid to you?"

Or is there maybe an even better way of doing it?

Comment: I really hate that if you insert any invalid value into a date column in mysql via php you get a '0000-00-00'!  It should either fail (preferred), leave it null, or set it to the declared default value of the field.

Comment: I did too, but think you can change that. Just need to enable strict mode or something: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates

Comment: Just like in the answer of @VolkerK actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2690242/39321 :)

Comment: You can always copy the data to a test system and try it out ;)

Comment: Yeah, enable strict mode, it also catches some other gotchas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose a server mode for the MySQL server that doesn't allow invalid date values a query containing such a malformed date representation will cause an error instead of (silently) assuming 0000-00-00
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

e.g.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id int auto_increment, d datetime, primary key(id))');

$query = "INSERT INTO foo (d) VALUES ('2010-02-31 12:15:18')";
foreach( array('ALLOW_INVALID_DATES', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES') as $mode ) {
  echo $mode, ": "; flush();
  $pdo->exec("SET SESSION sql_mode='$mode'");
  $pdo->exec($query);
  echo "Ok.\n";
}
```

prints

```
ALLOW_INVALID_DATES: Ok.
STRICT_ALL_TABLES: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2010-02-31 12:15:18' for column 'd' at row 1' in [...]
```

Comment: Good to know! Will look into setting that mode. With this I would have to actually try and then catch the exception though. Is there a way I can check it before I run the insert or update?

Comment: None that I know of. But does it matter whether a (fictional) function mysql\_check\_date() returns false or the execution of the query fails (with a specific error code)?

Comment: When I need it to validate user input, then yes, kind of. Especially if you want to do the check "client-side" using AJAX or something before submit.

Answer (score 10):

I use this syntax in my Application and it's work like charm!

```
SELECT DATE('2013-09-31') AS valid;
```

My System is Win7x64 with PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.6.16

Answer (score 6):

You could parse the date according to the format you want to use and then call checkdate to test if it's a valid date. Make sure you read the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php.

Answer (score 6):

Since the question states **MySQL**, here is a **MySQL** solution:

It is very difficult to verify if a field is a date because of all the different possible date formats that would need to be taken into account. BUT if you know that the field date formats are one of these:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd'
'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
'yyyy-mm-dd whatever'
```

This code will help you:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(`column`, '%Y-%m-%d')) IS NOT NULL
 AND `column` NOT REGEXP '^[0-9\.]+$'
```

Basically :

- the first condition tells you if is a date, but unfortunately doesn't exclude numbers (ex: `DATE(STR_TO_DATE(**1**, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '2001-00-00'`
- the second ensures that numbers are excluded, which leaves you with dates only that follow the formats above.

If `count(*)` is `>0` then it's a date, if it is `0` it's something else.

**Note**
This method works for strings of any date format as long as you know in advance what format they follow (which I know is not always the case but still helpful). Just replace the format `a priori` in the query

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a 'constant' query, without using temporary tables and test fields:

```
mysql> select day('2010-02-31 00:00:00');
+----------------------------+
| day('2010-02-31 00:00:00') |
+----------------------------+
|                       NULL | 
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't seem to work. I've come across a server where an update gave error 1292: `Incorrect datetime value: '2012-09-13T17:58:23+02:00'`, but `select day('2012-09-13T17:58:23+02:00')` gave 13.

Comment: This doesn't work if the field has '0' as a value, as day('0')=0. You should add day(column) is not null and day(column) <>0. See my answer for another method

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT WEEK(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;`

OR one of the:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
SELECT TO_DAYS(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
SELECT TO_SECONDS(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
SELECT WEEKDAY(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
SELECT YEARWEEK(col) IS NOT NULL AS valid;
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a value is a date you can use 
`day(dateToCheck) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
if(strtotime(trim($str)) {
    // persist trim($str) in db.        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in php to check for a valid date:

```
function valid_date($date) {
    return (preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/", $date));
}
```

Or as @VolkerK said if an invalid date is inserted into the database it will be stored as 0000-00-00 so you could also do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field > '0000-00-00'`

Comment: but this function returns true with '2010-32-56'

Comment: Yeah, that will weed out the dates in the wrong format, but doesn't take care of invalid dates. Is already using this for a pre-check though, except I use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. And the parenthesis isn't needed AFAIK: `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/`

Answer (score 0):

A simple PHP function that will validate MySQL data types of "date" and "datetime"
is in code sample that follows (chk_MySQL_Datetime). It validates by using createFromFormat() to
create a Date object for the date/date time if this fails then the date/datetime
is invalid. If a Date Object is created, a formatted string created with
date_format() and compared to the date/time .
If the strings are equal the date/datetime is valid.
If not equal the date/datetime are invalid. This comparison
is necessary because createFromFormat() will accept 2009/02/29 09:85 as a valid datetime
but MySQL will not.

The following code includes an example/test case that shows usage and test against a MySQL database.
To use the example you will have to replace $database->domysql_query() with call to a database. 
The output of the echos are included as comments immediately following the echo statements.

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns false if MySQL date or datetime value would be stored as
 * 0000-00-00  or 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
 * @param string $fmt - createFromFormat format of MySQL datetime value
 * to be tested. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
 * @param string $datetime MySQL datetime value
 * to be tested.
 * @return DateTime object formatted according to $fmt or FALSE if not
 * valid MySQL datetime value (would be inserted into the database
 * 0000-00-00 00:00:00);
 */
function chk_MySQL_Datetime($fmt, $datetime) {
    global $fmtdatetime;  // for example only
    $ckdate = DateTime::createFromFormat($fmt, $datetime);
    if ($ckdate !== FALSE) {
        $fmtdatetime = date_format($ckdate, $fmt);
        if ($fmtdatetime != $datetime) {
            $ckdate = FALSE;
        }
    }

    return $ckdate;
}
/*  Example/test of  chk_MySQL_Datetime */
/**
 * Creates table datetimetest if it doesn't exist
 * and insert a record in primary index of type datetime
 * then select record inserted and return result as a formated string.
 * @global type $database - addressibility to database functions
 * @global type $mysqlenum - MySql errornumber of last operation
 * @global type $fmtdatetime - $datetime formatted by date_format
 * @param type $datetime - datetime vale to be set
 * @return string of what was inserted
 */
function insert_in_table($datetime) {
    global $database, $mysqlenum, $fmtdatetime;
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datetimetest` (
  `MySQL_datetime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'datetime created by MySQL',
  `in_datetime` varchar(90) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date time string',
  `fmtdatetime` varchar(90) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Output of createFromFormat',
  PRIMARY KEY (`MySQL_datetime`)
) ;";
    $result = $database->domysql_query($sql, $database->connection, true);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `datetimetest`  WHERE MySQL_datetime='$datetime' OR `MySQL_datetime` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; ";
    $result = $database->domysql_query($sql, $database->connection, false);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `datetimetest` (MySQL_datetime, in_datetime, fmtdatetime)
       VALUES ('$datetime', '$datetime', '$fmtdatetime')";
    $result = $database->domysql_query($sql, $database->connection, false);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `datetimetest`  WHERE MySQL_datetime='$datetime' OR `MySQL_datetime` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; ";
    $result = $database->domysql_query($sql, $database->connection, false);
    $contxa = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $ret = " Inserted datetime = " . $contxa['in_datetime'] . "," .
            " MySQL stored " . $contxa['MySQL_datetime'] .
            ", fmtdatetime = " . $contxa['fmtdatetime'] . "<br>";
    return $ret;
}

        global $fmtdatetime;
        echo('<br>');
        $format = 'Y-m-d';
        $datetime = '2009-02-15'; // valid date
        $date = chk_MySQL_Datetime($format, $datetime);
        echo "Format: $format; datetime is " . ($date ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . " Expected $datetime is " . $fmtdatetime . "<br>";
 //echo output = Format: Y-m-d; datetime is valid Expected 2009-02-15 is 2009-02-15

        $result = insert_in_table($datetime);
        echo $result . "<br>";
 //echo output = Inserted datetime = 2009-02-15, MySQL stored 2009-02-15 00:00:00, fmtdatetime = 2009-02-15

        $datetime = '2009-02-29'; //invalid date
        $date = chk_MySQL_Datetime($format, $datetime);
        echo "Format: $format; datetime is " . ($date ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . " Expected $datetime is " . $fmtdatetime . "<br>";
 //echo output = Format: Y-m-d; datetime is invalid Expected 2009-02-29 is 2009-03-01

        $result = insert_in_table($datetime);
        echo $result . "<br>";
 //echo output =  Inserted datetime = 2009-02-29, MySQL stored 0000-00-00 00:00:00, fmtdatetime = 2009-03-01

        $format = 'Y-m-d H:i';
        $datetime = '2009-02-15 14:20';
        $date = chk_MySQL_Datetime($format, $datetime);
        echo "Format: $format; datetime is " . ($date ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . " Expected $datetime is " . $fmtdatetime . "<br>";
//echo output = Format: Y-m-d H:i; datetime is valid Expected 2009-02-15 14:20 is 2009-02-15 14:20

        $result = insert_in_table($datetime);
        echo $result . "<br>";
//echo output = Inserted datetime = 2009-02-15 14:20, MySQL stored 2009-02-15 14:20:00, fmtdatetime = 2009-02-15 14:20

        $datetime = '2009-02-15 14:63';  // invalid time
        $date = chk_MySQL_Datetime($format, $datetime);
        echo "Format: $format; datetime is " . ($date ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . " Expected $datetime is " . $fmtdatetime . "<br>";
//echo output = Format: Y-m-d H:i; datetime is invalid Expected 2009-02-15 14:63 is 2009-02-15 15:03

        $result = insert_in_table($datetime);
        echo $result . "<br>";
 //echo output = Inserted datetime = 2009-02-15 14:63, MySQL stored 0000-00-00 00:00:00, fmtdatetime = 2009-02-15 15:03

        $datetime = 'x-02-15 14:59';  // invalid time
        $date = chk_MySQL_Datetime($format, $datetime);
        echo "Format: $format; datetime is " . ($date ? 'valid' : 'invalid' ) . " Expected $datetime is " . $fmtdatetime . "<br>";
 //echo output = Format: Y-m-d H:i; datetime is invalid Expected x-02-15 14:59 is 2009-02-15 15:03

        $result = insert_in_table($datetime);
        echo $result . "<br>";
//echo output =  Inserted datetime = x-02-15 14:59, MySQL stored 0000-00-00 00:00:00, fmtdatetime = 2009-02-15 15:03
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to create a database with `BLACKHOLE` engine, read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html). And check the exception thrown by PDOException.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'p@s5W0Rd!!!', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

// CREATE DATABASE test;
// CREATE TABLE test.foo ( bar DATETIME ) ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;

try {
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    $dateTime = new DateTime();
    $dateTime = $dateTime->format('c');
    $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('".$dateTime."')");
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $errorInfo = $dbh->errorInfo();

    if ($e->getCode() === '22007'
        and $dbh->errorCode() === '22007'
        and $errorInfo[0] === '22007'
        and preg_match('/^incorrect datetime/', strtolower($errorInfo[2])) === 1) {

        throw new Exception($errorInfo[2], (int) $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## DATETIME - in SQL

```
SELECT your_unreliable_datetime_column, CAST(your_unreliable_datetime_column as DATETIME)
FROM some_cool_table
WHERE
CAST(your_unreliable_datetime_column as DATETIME) IS NOT NULL
AND
your_unreliable_datetime_column = CAST(your_unreliable_datetime_column as DATETIME)
```

This should only select valid `DATETIME`s, also ***should be applicable to `DATE` and `TIME` accordingly***, but not tested...

I did not found any documentation on `CAST()` return value on a convert failure, but [documentation covers a special case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) - a possible failure - which returns `NULL`:

> For conversion of a “zero” date string to a date, `CONVERT()` and `CAST()`
>   return `NULL` and produce a warning when the `NO_ZERO_DATE` SQL mode is
>   enabled.

Also, from my tests it *seems* that `CAST()` behaves the same on **any** convert failure - returns `NULL` and generates warning.

*I actually tested this on `MariaDB 10.0.30`*

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE('$value'), '%Y-%m-%d') = '$value'

when using Perl, $sth->rows will return zero if it fails

while $sth->rows will return nonzero if it succeeds

Answer (score 0):

It should resolve the issue within MySQL.

For pure DATE and TIME scenarios ( with DATETIME values you are OK to go AS IS ) - just CONCAT the initial value with any TIME or DATE string value to match your DB DATETIME format ( e.g. CONCAT( date_value, " 00:00:00") or CONCAT( "2021-12-31 ", time_value) ) - as variables in this sample *should_be* DATETIME formatted.

```
# declare variables
SET @invalid_date:='2021-02-30 25:64:64', @valid_date:='2021-02-28 04:01:01';

# check valid DATE scenario: invalid_date -> NULL; valid_date -> NOT NULL - correct value
SELECT DATE( @invalid_date );
SELECT DATE( @valid_date );

# check valid TIME scenario: invalid_date -> NULL; valid_date -> NOT NULL - correct value
SELECT TIME( @invalid_date );
SELECT TIME( @valid_date );

# check valid DATETIME scenario: invalid_date -> NULL; valid_date -> NOT NULL - correct value
SELECT CAST( @invalid_date AS DATETIME );
SELECT CAST( @valid_date AS DATETIME );

# purge variables
SET @invalid_date:= NULL, @valid_date:=NULL;
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

if (day(chk_date) is not null and day(chk_date)>0) then set chk_date=chk_date; else set chk_date= null;end if;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33698058)