# Check PHP datetime stamp is correct?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is there a way of checking whether a date time stamp is correct in PHP?

I am currently using `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in MySQL and would like to ensure when a user provides the date/time stamp in a form it matches the correct format.

Comment: You want a user to insert a time format  in `hh:mm:ss`? How many people would do that?

Comment: [This can be help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141315/php-check-for-a-valid-date-weird-date-conversions

Comment: In stackoverflow you can found many solution of this.

[Try with this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141315/php-check-for-a-valid-date-weird-date-conversions

Answer (score 6):

[until someone comes with good (bugfree), working checkdate() example ]
I am using this function:

```
<?php 
function validateMysqlDate( $date ){ 
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $date, $matches)) { 
        if (checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1])) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
} 

// check it: 
  $a = validateMysqlDate('2012-12-09 09:04:00');
  $b = validateMysqlDate('20122-12-09 09:04:00');
  $c = validateMysqlDate('2012-12_09 09:04:00');
  $d = validateMysqlDate('');
  var_dump( $a );
  var_dump( $b );
  var_dump( $c );
  var_dump( $d ); 
?>
```

and btw: checkdate() would return true for $b although it is not a valid mysql datetime

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `checkdate()` function to check the validity of a date.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

You can also pass all of the parts of your timestamp to `mktime()` and if false or -1 is returned (depending on PHP version) then it's an invalid date

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: What's the downvote for? Valid answer for the ambiguous question. The comments suggest that the OP wants to validate the pattern, not the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

This a duplicate question. For additiona discussion and answers see [MySQL: How to check if a string is a valid DATE, TIME or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690205/mysql-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-time-or-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the given string and then check it is the same date that you entered, note the below:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2011-01-32 12:00:00');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// outputs 2011-02-01 12:00:00
```

HTH.