# MySql - Load Local Data Infile - how to avoid insertion of row containing invalid data

Tags: mysql

I'm importing data from .csv file to Mysql db using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" query.
.csv contains foll:

```
ID | Name | Date | Price

 1. 01 | abc  | 13-02-2013 | 1500
 2. 02 | nbd  | blahblahbl | 1000
 3. 03 | kgj  | 11-02-2012 | jghj
```

My Mysql Table contains following columns:

```
Id INTEGER 
NAME Varchat(100)
InsertionTimeStamp Date
Price INTEGER
```

MySQL query to load .csv data to the table above :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'UserDetails.csv' INTO TABLE userdetails
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
 (Id,Name,InsertionTimeStamp,Price)
 set InsertionTimeStamp = str_to_date(@d,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

When I executed the query, 3 records got inserted into the table with 2 warnings

```
a) Incorrect datetime value : 'blahblahbl' for function str_to_date
b) Data truncate at row 3 (because of invalid INTEGER for Price column)
```

### Question

```
1. Is there any way to avoid data being inserted in table which shows warnings/errors or the row which has invalid data 

I dont want Row 2 & Row 3 to be inserted as it contains invalid data

2. For WARNING of Incorrect datetime value above, can I get the row no also?
Basically I want to get exact warning/error with the row number.
```

Comment: You can load the CSV into a temp table with x varchar columns, then do the validation on it.

Comment: No, as I dont know which column would contain an invalid data, it will become difficult to identify and validate thru temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be way more easy if you'd validate the input with some other language(for example php).
You'd just have to iterate through the lines of the csv and call something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141315/php-check-for-a-valid-date-weird-date-conversions)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690205/mysql-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-time-or-datetime)!

If you just have to fiddle with SQL, [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/14/bad-character-data-in-mysql/) might help!

Comment: I have no chance to validate .csv before importing it to mysql. I want to do it using mysql itself... Sorry, but the sql link you provided didnot help  me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool (CSV or TXT import format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).
In `Data Import` wizard on `Modes` page uncheck `Use bulk insert` oprion, on `Errors handling` page check `Ignore all errors` option, it will help you to skip import errors.

Comment: Sorry, but I guess you did not understand my question correctly. I said that I wanted to restrict row insertion if data is invalid in that row

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to skip problematic rows but don't you think you have a mistake in your LOAD DATA command? Should it be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'UserDetails.csv' INTO TABLE userdetails
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Id,Name,@d,Price)
set InsertionTimeStamp = str_to_date(@d,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

Shouldn't you be using the variable name (d) in the list of columns instead of the actual name of the column (InsertionTimeStamp)? That could be the reason why you are getting the error message about datetime.