# How to check if date stored in varchar field is a valid date or not in where clause of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update data in mysql table on basis of date field value.

Table consist of four fields (id, file_id, date_of_purchase, error). date_of_purchase and error are varchar fields.

Now i want to update error field if value in date is not a valid date. I tried with `STR_TO_DATE()` function but it is not working in `where clause` in `update query`

Here is my query

```
UPDATE `temp_bulk_upload_data` SET `error`= 'Date of purchase: Date of purchase should be a valid date' WHERE `file_id`='190' AND STR_TO_DATE(`date_of_purchase`, '%m/%d/%Y') IS NULL AND (`date_of_purchase` != '' OR `date_of_purchase` IS NOT NULL)
```

In this query i am getting this error:

```
Error in query (1411): Incorrect datetime value: '27/8/2018' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: You should not be using VARCHAR fields to store date values to begin with.

Comment: @misorude i know but it is already there in data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690205/mysql-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-time-or-datetime

Comment: "_but it is already there in data_" You could change it

Comment: @MickaelLeger I checked that. that is different thing i don't want to use for loops. i want to do it in single query.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? The behaviour you're getting seems to be exactly as described in the manual - it returns NULL and issues a warning (not note an error, a warning - AFAIK it won't stop the query from executing, but correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: BTW `AND (date_of_purchase != '' OR date_of_purchase IS NOT NULL)` doesn't make much sense - this will allow NULL values to be used, is that what you intended? It's not clear what this clause is meant to be doing. If the value is not `''` then either it's NULL or it's populated with something else. If it's populated with something else, then `IS NOT NULL` will allow for that already (and that will also allow `''`, since that's also a non-null value), whereas if it's NULL then it will be allowed through anyway. As far as I can see this clause doesn't prevent any rows from being included.

Comment: Hi, I think I found an exact dupe for your [newly deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52721447/3832970), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710236/function-to-create-regex-matching-a-number-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular expression in this case.
**Query**

```
WHERE `date_of_purchase` NOT REGEXP '^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\\/[0-9]{4}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Value passed in `STR_TO_DATE` should be of `mmddYYYY` format Or update second param of `STR_TO_DATE` function to accept `ddmmYYYY` format date value.

```
UPDATE `temp_bulk_upload_data` SET `error`= 'Date of purchase: Date of purchase should be a valid date' WHERE `file_id`='190' AND STR_TO_DATE(`date_of_purchase`, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NULL AND (`date_of_purchase` != '' OR `date_of_purchase` IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: But that is what i want to check wheater it is in correct format or not. This is the one way that i tried.